# How to handle HTML code that repeats a lot

Tags: php, html

I have some HTML code portions that repeat a lot through pages. I put this html code inside a function so that it is easy to maintain. It works perfectly. I, however feel this may not be very good practice.

```
function drawTable($item){
?>
   HTML CODE HERE
<?php
}
```

I also run into the problem that when I want to return data using json the following won't work as it will be NULL:

```
$response['table'] = drawTable($item);    
return json_encode($response);
```

What's the correct way to handle HTML code that repeats a lot??

Thanks

Comment: For the JSON, the function needs to return the data, you can't return an echoed out statement, or something that simply displays HTML.

Comment: *(reference)* See the section on [Web Presentation Patterns in POEAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into using templates instead of using ugly heredoc's or HTML-embedded-within-PHP-functions, which are just plain unmaintainable and are not IDE-friendly.

[What is the best way to include a php file as a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961392/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-a-php-file-as-a-template/)

If you have a repeating segment, simply load the template multiple times using a loop.

Although templates help with D.R.Y., the primary focus is to separate presentation from logic. Embedding HTML in PHP functions doesn't do that. Not to mention you don't have to escape any sort of quotes or break the indentation/formatting.

Example syntax when using templates:

```
$data = array('title' => 'My Page', 'text' => 'My Paragraph');

$Template = new Template();
$Template->render('/path/to/file.php', $data);
```

Your template page could be something like this:

```
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
```

Comment: sounds a lot like a framework. Consider a framework, it does all the plumbing code for you

Comment: Thanks a million! I think this will do the job for now. I didn't know about the extract() function. And yes, once I'm done with this project I will consider learning CakePHP or maybe Zend Framework.

Comment: The problem I'm finding with this approcah is that I am still not being able to return that html code as json. I thought about using something like DomDocumentFragment to load the html into a variable, but then I don't know how to use the extract() like that...

Comment: I've been reading for the past hour and it seems the way to fix this is to use output buffering

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawTable( $item ) { return '<p>something</p>'; }

function yourOtherFunction() {
$response['table'] = drawTable($item);    
return json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function definition

```
function drawTable($item){
  return 'HTML CODE HERE';
}
```

Called with

```
print drawTable($item);
```

Which will also work for your json return value.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But, I don't want to put the html code inside quotations because it is quite long chunks of html and it makes it hard to spot errors, it may involve dealing with escaping some characters and ending up with a mess... I'm trying to make the code as clean as possible